# Security for MMS media_urls

Tags: twilio

New to Twilio. Developing an IT alerting function with Twilio SMS/MMS API in Python. A postfix alias-executed program processes a message and sends essential data via Twilio MMS to designated recipients.

Media such as images are accessed through media_url property to  Client.messages.create(), via a URL pointing to content that I must store and offer through my HTTP server.

I have verified that that is the case, so my question is:

***How do I control access to those images so that only Twilio can access them, and only for the duration of the message sending process?***

My current solution, which is a kludge, is for the postscript alias-executed program to write a list of media files associated with the message, and then write my own status_callback that erases the files in that list when I get a "delivered" status (or a certain time limit expires).

This is a problem because the media files are publicly accessible for however long it takes for the "delivered" status to arrive or for my timeout to occur.

I've tried various searches but no applicable security mechanism has presented itself.

Answer (score 1):

I use Basic authentication and serve all my Twilio content from a dedicated directory which is password protected, Twilio seems quite happy to accept urls with inline username@password parameters.

I think Twilio publish a list of their IP address ranges somewhere too, so if you really want to lock your media directory down you could whitelist those and deny everything else access to that dir within your server config.

To delete them once they are processed I would probably write a basic script that is triggered by the Twilio status webhook and adds the filename of the image which can be deleted to a database table. I think you can pass some sort of verification tokens for Twilio to return with a callback for additional security.

Then run another script every few mins as a cron job (under a different user account with permission to delete files in your media dir) which reads the database, deletes any files listed from the directory and then clears the database ready for the next time.

**Edit**

Thinking about it you can probably delete the files as soon as Twilio has queued your message as I'm pretty sure they copy your media files to their server upon submission. These files are publicly accessible (but with names nobody is likely to guess). You can delete them with HTTP DELETE

Comment: Thanks for the response. Since the transit traffic to Twilio should be TLS encrypted, and my server forces TLS, providing basic auth in the URLs should be sufficient. Though hardcoding passwords, well... Not so great ;-)

My solution was to use a status_callback to a CGI on my server that erases the files associated with the request. I am verifying that Twilio reliably pulls the media files before I get any status callback. Right now I am deleting on failed, delivered, or undelivered status.

Thanks again, this at least confirms my concerns about the implementation.